# Google Sheets multiple results on multiple condition

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-statements, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to figure this out for the last one hour in Google...

In column B:B might be different strings "A", "B", "C".
In column C:C might be different values 1, 2, 3.
So, I want in column D:D 9 different string outputs "A1", "A2", "A3", "B1", "B2" and etc. depending on these three conditions.

As a basic one, I'm trying to do 2x2:

```
=IF(AND(B:B="A", C:C=1), "A1", IF(AND(B:B="A", C:C=2), "A2", IF(AND(B:B="B", C:C=1), "B1", IF(AND(B:B="B", C:C=2), "B2"))))
```

Please, can tell me what's wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SORT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(B1:B&CHAR(9)), COUNTA(C1:C)), CHAR(9)))&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(C1:C&CHAR(9), COUNTA(B1:B))), CHAR(9)))))
```

[image]

[image: 0]